# possible to fill JText Joomla with dynamic content

Tags: joomla1.7

Is possible to fill JText in Joomla with dynamic content and still using translation
or some body knows a workout for this situation

```
<?php echo JText::_( $this->catname[1]);?>
```

greetings Brem

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It's possible and you can use the translations too.